# Overriding validations in Rails Single Table Inhertiance models

Tags: validation, ruby-on-rails-4, activemodel

Let's say I have two models using Rails Single Table Inheritance.  I can easily add validations in child model to make certain field required.  But what if I want change validations making fields optional in Child model or have different criteria (like numericality)?

```
class Parent
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String
  field :age, type: Integer
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :age,   numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: 25 }
end
class Child < Parent
  # how can I make name optional in Child?  
  validates :age,   numericality: { less_than: 25 }
end
```

I can do with by creating custom validation methods and then overriding them in child class but I was hoping there was a way to do it just using default Rails validator format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this in Parent

```
validates :name, presence: true, unless: proc { |c| c.is_a? Child }
```

Not fantastic, but is pretty clean if you only have one subclass you want to override.  I am sure there are other approaches

Comment: thank you, that will work for my needs.  But open to other suggestions.

Comment: to run only on parents, you could do:

     validates :name, presence: true, if: proc { |c| c.is_a?  Parent }